# Get aws_lambda_event_source_mapping from sqs.tf and use it in lambda.tf

Tags: aws-lambda, terraform, amazon-sqs

I have my terraform setup this way:

```
lambda.tf
sqs.tf
```

In `lambda.tf`

```
locals {

  my_lambda = aws_lambda_function.vdf_lambda["my-lambda"]
  
}

...

environment {
    variables = {
      "MY_QUEUE_URL" = local.my_queue.id
      "MY_TRIGGER_ID"= local.my_queue_trigger.uuid
    }
}
```

in `sqs.tf`

```
locals {
  my_queue = aws_sqs_queue.fifo_queue["my-queue"]
  my_queue_trigger = aws_lambda_event_source_mapping.my_lambda_trigger
}

...

resource "aws_lambda_event_source_mapping" "my_lambda_trigger" {
  batch_size       = 1
  event_source_arn = aws_sqs_queue.fifo_queue["my-queue"].arn
  function_name    = local.my_lambda.function_name
}
```

When I run `terraform plan` I got this error:

```
Error: Cycle: local.my_lambda (expand), aws_lambda_event_source_mapping.my_lambda_trigger,
local.my_queue_trigger (expand), aws_lambda_function.my_lambdas
```

My guess is the trigger was not created yet when I try to get its UUID in `lambda.tf`. So how do I fix this? How to get the trigger UUID in `lambda.tf`?

Comment: The error is about `aws_lambda_function.my_lambdas`, yet no such resource is shown in your code. What exactly is `my_lambdas`? Basicially the error message does not match your code in the question.

Comment: It was not definitely that. I had to change the code to avoid posting details of the actual project. The part of concern is getting the `uuid` from resource `aws_lambda_event_source_mapping` in `sqs.tf` and use that in `lambda.tf`, which I guess is not created yet when try to be used in environment section of `lambda.tf`